# how to auto install npm packages on webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, package.json

I want to automate some tasks that I do all the time and
so I have two questions:

1. can I have all my npm packages point to a cache location (in package.json) 
   so I don't have to download if I already have, while I develop (also to save space), but change it 
   back to component names when I deploy?
2. I wanted to do something with webpack where if you type 'require'  in the 
   js files, it'll automatically "install" (with #1 method) the packages.

Can these be done? I want to automate lots of stuff that I'm doing and feel like this is a good starting point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1: that's what npm already does. If its cached version is not older than what you package.json says you need, nothing gets downloaded. 2: no you don't. That sounds convenient but also means you have no idea what your code needs. Keep that lists of dependencies explicit so tools like npm-check and greekeeper.io can do dependency checks and updates for you.

Comment: I agree with Mike. That's what npm does. No re-downloads. Also I don't think you install packages every day, so It shouldn't auto-install.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Mike, what do you mean by "you have no idea what your code needs"? Because I'm explicitly specifying what I'm 'require'ing and want things to go into package.json, it's just that I want webpack or maybe with grunt or via custom loader to pick this up and install on their own, or better yet point to the local cache. It's because I have lots of project folders and they locally have same components in each folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically:

1. As [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) and [Louy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644422/louy) said, you don't need to care about the 're-downloads' of npm, since it already cares about it behind the scenes.
2. I stumbled upon the [auto-install-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/renke/auto-install-webpack-plugin) today while looking for something similar and it seems to be what you're describing. I haven't tested it yet, though.

I can edit this answer after testing it, but let me know if you do it first.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that.